# How to interface an hardware device using javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I had developed a web application in ASP.NET MVC using C# which is used for billing purpose. But now the client had a new requirement that he need to connect swiping device so that the customers can pay using their cards.
Now the issue is that how i communicate with the device from javascript? i had tried web socket but is not succeed.Is there any ways to make this possible ?

Comment: We discourage posts that simply state a problem out of context, and expect the community to solve it. Assuming you tried to solve it yourself and got stuck, it may be helpful if you wrote your thoughts and what you could not figure out. It will definitely draw more answers to your post. Until then, the question will be voted to be closed / downvoted.

Comment: How this got 2 upvotes is beyond me. No [mcve] or shown attemtps, not even any information about the kind of system the OP is working with.

Comment: Here comes the SO Police :D

Comment: Please look at http://docs.kioskproapp.com/article/846-swipe-mercurypay#sample-code

Comment: Google Chrome provides [USB](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/usb)
 and [Serial](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/serial) API for Chrome Apps

Comment: Maybe helpful
https://blog.kiosksimple.com/2015/01/21/accepting-card-present-transactions-from-your-website-with-javascript/

Comment: @Sandeep Please follow below instruction-
https://blog.kiosksimple.com/2017/06/22/parse-credit-card-data-javascript/#more-16859

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **self host Web API** to communicate with the swiping device.

- You can simply create a self hosted Web API to communicate with the swiping device
- Make it run on the client machine
- Call the API from your java script

It will work perfectly

Comment: thanks for the reply, You mean we need to install an addition application in client side. Right ?

Comment: Yes. We can self host Web API using a console application and windows service. I have already tried it using console application. In this case I have the console application running in client machine.

Comment: let me try and get back.

Answer (score -2):

Look at the documentation of the swiping device, it should explain how you should interface with it.

Of course there's no web browser API to interface with every imaginable peripheral device, so you're simply going to have to put your software development skills to work and create a compatibility layer.

Comment: thanks for the reply but it may not possible. We need to communicate the device via socket.

Comment: It may not be possible without installing additional software on the user's computer since the browser doesn't expose any raw sockets or syscalls and for very good reason. But I'm certain it's possible one way or the other.